# What does the function Collections.reverseOrder() do?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

```
int min=Collections.min(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

What will be the output after executing the `reverseOrder` function?

Comment: Hello! Have you tried this code? I guess you can get the answer by executing the code and printing the values :)

Comment: The JavaDoc is just a few clicks away ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like an interview question about [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/Collections.html):

Now, `Collections.reverseOrder` is a `Comparator` that inverts the normal order, `>` becomes `<` and vice versa.

Hence the following statements are the same:

```
int max = Collections.min(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
int max = Collections.max(list);
```

And the result is the *maximum* instead.

There are no real speed penalties, as the list itself is not modied, the list is not copied. The complexity for a `List` is **O(N)**: all elements need to be traversed.

Using a `SortedSet` like `TreeSet` instead of a `List` would be better - when feasible.

Comment: I got the same output as you have told but there is a bit of doubt for me to confirm. Now I am clear with the concept.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Collections.reverseOrder()` method is a `java.util.Collections` class method.

According to the javadoc:

> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering
>   on a collection of objects that implement the `Comparable` interface.
>   The natural ordering is the ordering imposed by the objects' own
>   compareTo method `public static  Comparator reverseOrder()`

You can find some other good examples on the following site:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-reverseorder-java-examples/

In your case the following expressions are equivalent:

```
 Collections.min(list, Collections.reverseOrder()) 

 Collections.max(list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, this function simply inverts your numbers and they are low. Check this example, I hope you will understand what it does.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 5, 23, 2, 3);
        nums.stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        nums.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where's `Collections.reverseOrder()` being used in this code?

Comment: In this code I've used streams, so Collections.reverseOrder() is used in sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()). Result is the same as you write Collections.sort(nums, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: This is a suggestion using a different logic and this works fine. Now I came to know what is streams too.

Answer (score 3):

sometimes it's better to see for yourself with the source code.

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
    return (Comparator<T>) ReverseComparator.REVERSE_ORDER;
}
```

`REVERSE_ORDER` is simply an object of `ReverseComparator` inner class.

```
  static final ReverseComparator REVERSE_ORDER = new ReverseComparator();
```

Comment: Suggestions sounds good to know till the implicit operations. Thanks